# Django DRF multi model view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wanna retrieve few models in a single request so i'll get:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "foo"
    }
  ],
  "trucks": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "goo"
    }
  ],
  "bikes": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "doo"
    }
  ],
}
```

for that I've create a serializer:

```
class VehiclesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    cars = CarSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    trucks = TruckSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    bikes = BikeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

and a view:

```
class VehiclesListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = ???????
    serializer_class = VehiclesSerializer
```

but as you can see, I haven't manage to figure out how to write the queryset.

Any help?

### UPDATE:

Just to clarify my question. There is no Vehicle model. 
That's why I'm **NOT** writing the regular 
`queryset = Vehicles.objects.all()`

Comment: Can you show the `Vehicles` model?

Comment: What about `Vehicles.objects.all()`? Then you will get also detail view of each item available on `/api/vehicles/pk`

Comment: there is no Vehicles model.... that's all the point of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best that I've got was without using generics:

```
class VehiclesListView(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ser = VehiclesSerializer({
        'cars': Car.objects.all(),
        'trucks': Truck.objects.all(),
        'bikes': Bike.objects.all()
    })

    return JsonResponse(ser.data)
```

Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I think. The two cleanest ones would be:

1. Have different endpoints for your models. This feels like the most RESTful approach to me.
2. Create a VehicleModel that is `ForeignKey` related to your other models. That should even work with the Serializer you have written.

The 2nd approach would look something like this for the models:

```
# models.py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    pass

class Truck(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='trucks')

....
```

And like this for the views:

```
#views.py
class VehiclesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Vehicle.objects.prefetch_related('cars', 'trucks', 'bikes').all()
    serializer_class = VehiclesSerializer
```

Note on the `prefetch_related()` in there: Django will use four DB queries to get your objects, one for each related model and one for the main model. If you use `Vehicle.objects.all()` by itself, the Serializer will create a DB requests for *every* `Vehicle` it encounters. See [Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

If you don't want to do that, you can always override `ListAPIView.list` with your custom logic, even bypass the serializer completely:

```
class VehiclesListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cars = Cars.objects.values('id', 'name')
        trucks = Trucks.objects.values('id', 'name')
        bikes = Bikes.objects.values('id', 'name')

        out = {
            'trucks': trucks,
            'cars': cars,
            'bikes': bikes,
        }
        return Response(out)
```

Note on using `values()` instead of `all()`: You don't really use any other model fields in your serializer, so there's no use in querying extra fields. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

Comment: I know i can have different endpoints for each one and i even wrote that already for other purposes, but this one meant to save requests for the server. your other option did work for me but i've voted up for your effort and good will.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the API [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/).

queryset = Vehicles.objects.all();

or to get random 100 or 10 objects:

```
Vehicles.objects.all().order_by('?')[:100]
```

or

```
Vehicles.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = Vehicles.objects.all()
```

Or if you need to filter on datetime or request properties.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Vehicles.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [DjangoRestMultipleModels](https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels)

The documentation is beautiful.

In your case the view would look like this:

```
from drf_multiple_model.views import MultipleModelAPIView

class VehicleView(MultipleModelAPIView):
    queryList = [
        (Car.objects.all(),CarSerializer),   #(queryset,Serializer)
        (Truck.objects.all(),TruckSerializer),
        (Bike.objects.all(), BikeSerializer),
]
```

Hope this helps someone..